# Fetch details from catalog_product_flat_1 table

Tags: magento-1.9, product, module, collection, catalog

In `catalog_product_flat_1` table, we created a custom column **custom_uid** & saving **customer ids**

Assume below image is the `catalog_product_flat_1` table. You can see the columns contain Product name and customer id.

[image]

We are trying to fetch Product information from `catalog_product_flat_1` table & trying to display in **My account** section. but its not fetching.

Means in customer with id **101**'s account, we are trying to display **Product 1 & product2** . & in in customer id **102**'s account, we are trying to display **Product 3**

**app/code/local/Amasty/Example/Block - List.php**

```
class Amasty_Example_Block_List extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
 public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $idc = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId();
     $customerSavedProductArray = array();
     $customerSavedProductArray = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('custom_uid',$idc)->getColumnValues("name");
//  $customerSavedProductArray = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addFieldToFilter('custom_uid',$idc)->getColumnValues("name");
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array("in"=>$customerSavedProductArray));

    $collection->load();
    $this->setCollection($collection);
    }
```

**phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
<?php $collections = $this->getCollection(); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>


<?php foreach ($collections as $key => $product) {

    echo $product->getName().' <br><br>';
    echo $product->getId().'<br><br>';  
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());  

?>
```

**update**

In config.xml, i used table name : `catalog_product_flat_1`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Amasty_Example>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Amasty_Example>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <example>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Amasty_Example</module>
                    <frontName>example</frontName>
                </args>
            </example>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <example>
                    <file>example.xml</file>
                </example>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <events>

        <controller_action_predispatch>
            <observers>
                <Amasty_Example>
                    <class>example/observer</class>
                    <method>onControllerActionPredispatch</method>
                </Amasty_Example>
            </observers>
        </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>       
    </frontend>


    <global>
        <models>
            <example>
                <class>Amasty_Example_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>example_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </example>
            <example_mysql4>
                <class>Amasty_Example_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <example>
                        <table>example</table>
                    </example>
                     <mydesign>
                        <table>catalog_product_flat_1</table>
                    </mydesign>
                </entities>
            </example_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <example_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Amasty_Example</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </example_setup>
            <example_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </example_write>
            <example_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </example_read>
        </resources>

    </global>
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are doing it wrong.
You should never manually add columns to any `catalog_product_flat_*` table.
These tables is just an index of the active products for each store view.
When you rebuild the indexes, these tables are regenerated. If you add a column to it you will lose it on the next reindex.
You should add a product attribute called `custom_uid` with the flag `used in product listing` set to `yes`.
Then reindex everything.
After that you can get the products collection for a specific customer like this:

```
$customerId = 8; //your customer id here - it can come from session
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') // instead of * you can put an array with only the attributes you need
    ->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('custom_uid', $customerId);
```

Then you can simply loop through the collection and do something with each product, but don't use `load` in the foreach loop.

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    //do something with $product
}
```